# How can I install Craft Commerce 2 alpha release?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, craft3, composer

I tried following the installation instructions here: https://docs.craftcms.com/commerce/v2/installation.html

When I run `composer install craftcms/commerce`, it says:

> Invalid argument craftcms/commerce. Use "composer require craftcms/commerce" instead to add packages to your composer.json.

So I then ran `composer require craftcms/commerce`, and it says:

> [InvalidArgumentException]   Could not find package craftcms/commerce
>   at any version for your minimum-stability (alpha). Check the package
>   spelling or your mini   mum-stability

I have added `"craftcms/commerce":"@alpha"` in the require field in `composer.json` also changed minimum stability to alpha `("minimum-stability": "alpha")`.

But it still is not working. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to contact P&T (at support@craftcms.com) directly to get installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are no public releases of Commerce 2 (for Craft 3) yet. According to the [official launch faq](https://craftcms.com/news/craft-3-launch-faq):

> **When will Commerce 2 be released?** We will release Commerce 2 Beta on April 4 alongside Craft 3 GA. If you need access to Commerce 2
>   beforehand, or you are a plugin developer hoping to get started on a
>   Commerce integration, get in touch for advanced access. We expect the
>   beta will last about three to six months.

Looks like the GitHub repo you linked to is where they're compiling the docs in preparation for April 4th. If you want access to the `alpha` version or whatever, looks like you should contact Pixel & Tonic for pre-release access.